# Why are only some questions highlighted?

Tags: support, tag-highlighting

When I am visiting [the Ruby on Rails tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), I see only some questions as highlighted. Why so?

"Ruby on rails" is added in my favorite tag list. So it should highlight all the questions..

A preview (see full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A5Gd.jpg)):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have `ruby-on-rails` selected and not just `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby`?

Comment: Have mercy on my scroll-wheel and crop the screenshot, please.

Comment: @DanielFischer I edited it.

Comment: Better, but more cropping would be welcome. Four lines should be enough to illustrate the point.

Comment: added 15 questions list ...

Comment: @Suma I cannot cut the upper part because it shows what the fave tag is; this is the least! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you're viewing the questions page under a favourite tag (as you are here), only questions that have **another** of your favourite tags **as well** are highlighted.

This holds even if you are viewing the questions under a *combination* of tags - there must be a further favourite tag for the question to be highlighted. So for me, when I view [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions and then click [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) over on the 'Related Tags' on the right, I get [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#+asp.net), and only questions with *another* of my favourite tags (above and beyond [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)) are highlighted.

I only know this because I worked it out myself. I've gone looking for a reference for this, but the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-tagged [post about highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) didn't mention this particular facet, so I've added it there.

Answer (score 2):

The site does not highlight questions in a tag search unless they have *another* tag that you have also favorited. If it did highlight all of the questions tagged [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) in your case, all of the questions would be highlighted. This would not emphasize any of the questions over any others, so the highlighting would be useless.