# Why does this question have a blue highlight?

Tags: support, highlighting, newest-questions

Whenever I scroll through 'newest questions' some of the questions highlighted in blue, for example:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: The answer is already in that image...

Comment: @Cai How can this be a duplicate as I didn't knew that this is due to my favourite tag?

Comment: What does `Also, let me know you that it isn't because I haven't clicked that link in my browser.` mean?

Comment: @JaideepKhare because that question explains that it is due to your favourite tags?

Comment: It's not why people are destroying the question but why you didn't use search at all https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135118/why-are-only-some-questions-highlighted https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/why-do-some-questions-in-question-lists-have-a-yellow-background https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71928/background-color-of-stack-overflow-questions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292649/what-is-use-of-background-colour-in-question-lists https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250554/random-questions-in-the-newest-tab-come-with-background-colour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's how it shows up when you have a tag that you marked as one of your favorite tags. In your screenshot, that question has the tag that I see in your favorite tags list, on the right.

From the [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do):

> Questions with these tags become highlighted on the front page.